# Como mostrar un alert si mi input incrementa el valor?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Buenas tengo un input donde le llevo un value desde la base de datos, basicamente es un select COUNT, y este valor se lo paso por ajax al input, pero necesito que cuando el value aumente o cambie de valor me muestre un alert.

Aqui le llevo el value a mi input con id first_alert

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function alerta(){
            var id = <?= $_SESSION['tienda'] ?>;
            $.ajax({
                url:"../controlador/pedido/alerta.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{id:id},
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#first_alert').val(data.cuenta);
                }
            })
        }
        setInterval(alerta, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Solo necesita recibir el evento change del input.     input.addEventListener("change", function(){   alert("hola");  })

Comment: Hola, esto seria una función aparte?, o donde colocaría este evento  :D

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de dos maneras, con keyup puedes controlar cuando escribes y cambias el valor del input y con change puedes lanzar el valor del imput cuando este cambie

Veo que estás usando JQUERY:

Con JQUERY te quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function alerta(){
            var id = <?= $_SESSION['tienda'] ?>;
            $.ajax({
                url:"../controlador/pedido/alerta.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{id:id},
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#first_alert').val(data.cuenta);
                    $("input").change(function(){
                         alert("el valor del input ha cambaido!!!.");
                    });
                }
            })
        }
        setInterval(alerta, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

y lo del keyup lo puedes hacer antes de la llamada AJAX:

```
$("input").on('keyup change', function(){
// te mostrará un alert cada que hagas algo dentro del input ya sería de adaptarlo a que quieras pero te dej
    alert("el valor del input ha cambiado.");
  });
```

ref: [change](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_change_ref)

[keyup](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_keydown_keyup)

Comment: Hola oscar, no me detecta el evento change, ese input la idea es tenerlo oculto para que cuando llegue un pedido este input cambie (numero de pedidos) y me salte una alerta. No se si tenga que ver que lo ejecuto cada segundo con SetInterval :C

Comment: Puedes debes ponerlo fuera, poir que lo he puesto dentro de la llamada AJAX, ponlo al principio si no y me dices